# Замена надписи в dropdown Bootstrap 4

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap4

Есть combobox выполненный средствами bootstrap 4, типа:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Корпоратив
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Корпоратив</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Банкет</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Свадьба</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Другое</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вопросы**

1. Как сделать так, чтобы после выбора элемента изменялась надпись в комбобоксе? На примере выше, если я выбираю, допустим, "Банкет". Комбобокс должен закрыться, и вместо изначальной надписи "Корпоратив" должна стать надпись "Банкет".
2. Выбранное значение мне нужно передавать в качестве поля формы - что и откуда будет передаваться?

**ADD:** Может имеет смысл просто использовать `<select>` и его немного переоформить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown это не ComboBox. Dropdown предназначен скорее для выбора пункта меню, а для выбора значения поля обычно используют select. См. [The "select" Element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp) Для придания ему бутстраповского внешнего вида используйте класс form-control.

Comment: Спасибо! Так и есть. Есть еще "bootstrap-select", работает именно так, как мне хотелось бы, а ля "Dropdowns".